# Xcode Developer account login failed

Tags: xcode, development-environment

Hey i'm trying to login in to my development account in xcode preference. But I'm getting below error. I tried from more then hour but it gives same error.[image: Error Snap]

And when i check other already added accounts also get expired session.

Answer (score 0):

The 503 error code you're getting is the HTTP status code, indicating that the server is unavailable, in this case, the authentication server. It could be that the system is under a denial of service attack, or it may just be down for maintenance.

You can read a little more about the error code [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.4).

Comment: Then what should i do to login

Comment: You have to wait for it to come back online. I'm surprised you had to wait an hour already, so I can't say how long it will take.